# Is it Possible to Remove the Shadow on a JButton Icon?

Tags: java, swing, click, jbutton

My questing is pretty much already asked in the title. When you click a (Java Swing) `JButton` you get a type of hover effect or a "shadow" over the icon of the `JButton`. Is it possible to remove this shadow to make the button icon appear in the same way as it does when not clicked?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could call [setRolloverIcon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setRolloverIcon-javax.swing.Icon-) with the result of [getIcon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#getIcon--).

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware of these functions. I was rather looking for setPressedIcon but I found that in the article you provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `button.setBorder(null);` This will remove all of the graphics for the button and therefore the button will look the same whether it has been pressed or not.